# Radium doesn't work on OS X Catalina

Tags: catalina, macos

I was using [Radium](http://catpigstudios.com/) on OS X Mojave. When I upgraded to Catalina, it stopped working.  Unfortunately, it appears that the developer has stopped working on it.

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: [RoaringApps](https://roaringapps.com/app/radium) says no data since Yosemite. The dev's site, CatPig has "Copyright © 2009-2016", so I'd say it's not promising. You cannot run 32-bit apps on Catalina. You might be able to set up an older VM, but that's going to be about it. Personally, I've tried it before with abandoned apps, need to run old app, fire up VM with it on, work 10 mins, close it down… you quickly tire of it & find an alternative that's less effort...

Comment: Too bad the author hasn't released the application as open source.  I tweeted `@CatPigStudios` with that request.  I'm not expecting a response.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a patch for Radium to make it work on Catalina (and hopefully later macOSs as well).
https://github.com/zvonicek/radium-fix-launcher

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I wouldn't expect a new version since its pretty clear Radium is not being maintained.
I'm using [OneRadio](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/oneradio/id992484531?mt=12) now, not exactly the same, but still pretty good/similar to Radium imo.

Comment: I installed that as well.  It's OK.